# Using Protovis with R

Tags: r, protovis

As question, I have satisfied with what `R` and `ggplot2` can do for static graph, but what about interactive graphs? How combine R and Protovis to make the graphs?

There is somethings called [rwebvis](http://code.google.com/p/rwebvis/) but seems it is no longer active.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first you need a web server. Ooh, R has one of those now. Then you need some way of generating output on the web from R code - ooh, R has one of those too:

http://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/4-lines-of-r-to-get-you-started-using-the-rook-web-server-interface/

So you can then write R server pages that return JSON-encoded data that you can feed to Protovis - or if you want to get right up to date, to D3, which is Protovis++ and made of win.

Answer (score 1):

Iplots is a fairly useful package that allows interactive graphing ( by this I mean selection linking between graphs, color linking, etc).  It has some limitations and is not really made for producing plots as much as exploring data trends.

Acinonyx also was recently updated which is supposed to be an updated version of iplots, but from what I can tell it still has some work to do.

Not familiar with protovis or rwebvis.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package from google called [googlevis](http://code.google.com/p/google-motion-charts-with-r/) that enables some interactivity. This produces plots that are embeddable online. If you like protovis, the same author has another library called [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/protovis.html).

For running R on a webserver, I have been experimenting with [RApache](http://rapache.net/), which enables you to link your R installation to an apache server.

If the interactivity does not to be online, [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/) have a package called [manipulate](http://www.rstudio.org/docs/advanced/manipulate) which may also be of interest.